# Is it possible for the rationality of a computable number to be unknowable?

Tags: computability, rationality-testing

**Main question:** Suppose we have some real number $x$ that is proven to be not only be computable, but has had such an algorithm explicitly found. Could it be the case that it may be impossible to prove or disprove the rationality of $x$?

Along the same notion, if we have proven that a number's rationality status is knowable, does that prove the number is computable?

More generally, how is the knowledge of computability of a number related to the ability of knowing its rationality status?

This is a strange thought, and I have absolutely no intuition towards or against such a possibility.

Comment: Computable is fairly weak...define, say, a binary decimal by saying that it's $n^{th}$ digit is $1$ if the $n^{th}$ prime is the first of a twin prime pair, and $0$ otherwise.  That could well be rational (it is, if there are only finitely many twin primes, for instance).  And we can compute each digit in a finite manner.

Comment: @lulu that's a good example, but this example doesn't necessarily prove that such number's rationality is unknowable. However, I do see your point that a number's digits could be related to a (possibly) unknowable statement.

Comment: Do you mean a non-constructive proof that some specific number $x$ is rational ? As long as we can compare $x$ to any rational number, we can in principle determine the fraction within a finite time. But in practice this can be infeasible because it takes too much time and/or memory.

Comment: Even the algebraic numbers are computable. To determine a number exactly is a stronger requirement and can easily lead to the equality problem. If we have a sequence we might be unable to determine whether it converges exactly to $2$ or to a number extremely near to $2$.

Comment: @Peter I am afraid I am not too familiar with constructive/non-constructive proofs. But if I follow, I am assuming that $x$ is an explicit real number that we know how to compute to arbitrary precision, if that means anything to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to talk about provability/decidability we need to specify a background set of axioms - no statement is undecidable in all systems, for silly reasons. I'm going to assume we're working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but what follows isn't specific to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ at all.

For a sentence $\varphi$, define a sequence of natural numbers $k_n$ ($k\in\mathbb{N}$) as follows: $k_n=1$ iff EITHER $n$ is a power of $2$ OR $\varphi$ is provable from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in $\le n$ steps, and $k_n=0$ otherwise. The number $$\xi_\varphi:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{k_n\over 2^n}$$ is then guaranteed - provably in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or indeed much less - to be rational iff $\varphi$ is provable from $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Now a quick corollary to Godel's theorem shows that the general problem of deciding whether a sentence is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provable is undecidable (basically, otherwise we could use a greedy algorithm to whip up a consistent computable completion of $\mathsf{ZFC}$). So there is in general no way to decide whether $\xi_\varphi$ is rational. In fact this can be made explicit: for each "reasonable" theory $T$ we can whip up a specific sentence $\psi_T$ such that $T$ cannot decide whether $\xi_{\psi_T}$ is rational or not.

*(Note that the above has essentially nothing to do with rationality per se - pretty much any nontrivial property of numbers will be subject to some variant of this argument.)*